# Database creation and management

Tags: rdbms

I was hoping you could help me with this project. I was tasked with the creation of a simple database that will include a few tables and some forms and reports. I have no problem with the design part, or the querying or any of the technical issues. I just have no idea what software I can use to actually have that single user database on one pc (i.e.not web based) where it will be tested. I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: What do you mean by some forms and reports. Those would be add ons to an RBDMS. Unless you were using something like Ms Access or Oracle Forms , you's be writing forms and reports in the app language e.g. php. If you mispoke, just install mysql, seeing as you know it.

Comment: What I have done before was create an application that was hosted on a server to which i connect using php. I made the forms using html elements and when submitted they updated the tables accordingly. I am in no way implying that I know more than I do, just asking for some guidance as to how would you implement such an application without having it being hosted on a server. I am trying to just keep everything on a single pc where forms created will be filled by personnel and then the data entered accordingly and tables updated so that reports reflect the changes.

Comment: Erm you just make your PC the server. As in install say mysql and apache and configure it.

Comment: Thank you for your time sir, I appreciate it. And BTW, I'm only a first year software dev student, not a field expert claiming knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Use MS Access if you have it. The setup is minimal and it does not need a server of any kind.

Comment: I have never used it, I have basic knowledge in it, any links to some good guides?

Comment: I have only implemented database projects on web applications, using PhP, HTML MySQL etc...